# setting up Ajax Calls in Magento

Tags: jquery, ajax, magento

I am trying to setup jquery ajax in Magento. I have successfully set up a custom page and am trying to setup an ajax on that page. The jquery works but ajax doesn't seem to be doing anything. What's weird is that I don't get any errors.
my config.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
<JJ_LooseDiamonds>
  <version>0.1.0</version>
</JJ_LooseDiamonds>
</modules>
<frontend>
  <routers>
    <loosediamonds>
    <use>standard</use>
      <args>
        <module>JJ_LooseDiamonds</module>
        <frontName>loosediamonds</frontName>
      </args>
  </loosediamonds>
</routers>
    <layout>
      <updates>
        <loosediamonds>
          <file>loosediamonds.xml</file>
        </loosediamonds>
      </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
<global>
<helpers>
  <loosediamonds>
    <class>JJ_LooseDiamonds_Helper</class>
  </loosediamonds>
</helpers>
<blocks>
  <loosediamonds>
    <class>JJ_LooseDiamonds_Block</class>
  </loosediamonds>
</blocks>
</global>
</config>
```

then, my layout looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>   
<layout version="0.1.0">   
  <loosediamonds_index_index>   
    <reference name="root">   
      <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template> </action>   
   </reference>
  <reference name="left">   
    <block type="loosediamonds/left" name="loosediamonds_left"  template="loosediamonds/left.phtml"/>   
  </reference>   
  <reference name="content">   
    <block type="loosediamonds/index" name="loosediamonds_index" template="loosediamonds/index.phtml"/>   
    <block type="loosediamonds/product" name="loosediamonds_product" template="loosediamonds/product.phtml" />
  </reference>   
</loosediamonds_index_index>   
</layout>
```

my index.phtml which is the main custom page has an ajax implementation:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {

    $(".diamondtable tr").click ( function () {
        var data = "id="+$(this).data("id");

        try {
            jQuery.ajax({
                url:"<?php echo $this->getUrl('product.phtml') ?>",
                dataType:'jsonp',
                type:'post',
                data:data,
                success:function (data) {
                    alert (data);
                }
            });
        } catch (e) {
            alert (e);
        }           
    })
})(jQuery)
```

and the product.phtml has the code that retrieves the product information and should technically pass it back to index.phtml. I have looked through several examples but non are addressing the problem I am having. I was wander if anyone would be able to help me with my dilemma. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try using Firebug for Firefox or Chrome Inspect Element to see what data is posted and return from the server?

Comment: when I remove dataType: 'jsonp', my alert gets fired under success. However, I get the whole html code back instead of just an echo which is that's all I have in products.phtml

Comment: Take a look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7448617/ajax-in-magento it would be much better to put you ajax logic in your controller instead of in a phtml file

Comment: indeed, it helped me out. I actually placed my code in the IndexController instead of using it on a separate phtml page. I finally got it to work. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding complete and error methods to the ajax call. This will help determine whether you are actually receiving a response.

For example:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"<?php echo $this->getUrl('product.phtml') ?>",
    dataType:'jsonp',
    type:'post',
    data:data,
    success:function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
         alert(textStatus);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
        alert(textStatus);
    },
    complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
        alert(textStatus);
    },
});
```

This may help you debug the problem better than a try catch statement.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look @ [Ajax In Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7448617/ajax-in-magento)

1. Debug your ajax request using Firebug for Firefox or Chrome Inspector
2. It would be much better to put you ajax logic in your controller instead of in a phtml file